# Адаптирование сайта

Tags: html, css

У меня сайт www.bakunights.ml я хочу адаптировать этот сайт под устройствам смартфоны т.д как это сделать чтоб когда вошли с смартфона по-другому сайт отображалась для устройства думаю поняли помогите?

Comment: на фрилансе идите и за вас сделают .. раз уж сами не умеете

Comment: это мой собственный сайт не фриланс могу вам доказать даже

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media

Comment: у меня такая проблема мой сайт:www.bakunights.ml там у меня footer есть я добавляю <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-witdh initial-scale=1.0" и как только с смартфона вошел footer-а как бы обрезает что ли знаете как решить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут есть море вариантов...

- Сделать адаптивный шаблон

  - FlexBox
  - FlexBox + Smartgrid (рекомендую)
  - Bootstrap
- Сделать определение устройства на сервере ([**mobile detect**](http://mobiledetect.net/) в помощь) и для каждого устройства отдавать свой шаблон (очень рекомендую для больших проектов)

Вы также можете найти еще варианты, которые будут Вам по душе)))

Comment: блогадарю вас помогли

Answer (score 0):

1) В head добавьте `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

2)Добавьте [медиазапросы](http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media)

Comment: а вы знаете сделать так чтобы вот когда кто то  с телефона зашел и редирект на m.domain.com было?

Comment: создать субдомен